# BIRT concatenation with group by from XML source

Tags: group-by, concatenation, birt

[image]

^^^^^^^
My results look like this.^^^^^ I'm grouping by the Number.
I'm trying to concatenate the Name so it will limit the rows.
When I do concatenate the Name  it looks like this.
[image]

My problem is that it is not limiting the rows and I'm not sure how to do a distinct value. I've tried suppress duplicates values on the rows but that but makes the rows blank and leaves the records.
I would like to have the results look like this.
[image]

Any help would be great